# Determine Least time taken to click - Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var startTime;

function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color = color + letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function makeShapeAppear() {
  var top = Math.random() * 400;
  var left = Math.random() * 400;
  var width = (Math.random() * 200) + 100;
  document.getElementById("shape").style.width = width + "px";
  document.getElementById("shape").style.height = width + "px";
  document.getElementById("shape").style.top = top + "px";
  document.getElementById("shape").style.left = left + "px";
  document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "block";
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "50%";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("shape").style.borderRadius = "0%";
  }
  document.getElementById("shape").style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
  startTime = new Date().getTime();
}

function shapeAfterDelay() {
  setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, (Math.random() * 2000));
}

shapeAfterDelay();

document.getElementById("shape").addEventListener("click", function(js) {
  document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";
  var endTime = new Date().getTime();
  var timeTaken = ((endTime - startTime) / 1000);
  document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = timeTaken;
  shapeAfterDelay();
});
```

I have made a game in Javascript in which the user clicks on the shapes and the browser displays the time taken by him to click on that shape.
Now I also want to determine the least time taken by the user amongst all his clicks but not able to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Hello, show us what code have you achieved so far.

Comment: it would be easy if you can post the code here for our reference

Comment: @JakubTobiasz I have added to the post

Comment: @THEWOLF I have added to the Post.

Comment: you can use an array instead of a single variable, where you store the times.

Comment: @MaxG And how to determine least time taken from the values stored in array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. You want the least time of reaction. So first of all you can define a variable to hold the best time. Below `var startTime;` you can add

```
var bestTime = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
```

You assign the max possible value, because it's the easiest way to compare if something else is lower at the first time.

Then you calculate your current time, what you have achieved. Now you just compare if your `timeTaken` is lower than `bestTime`.

```
if (timeTaken < bestTime)
  bestTime = timeTaken;
```

And now `bestTime` stores the least time ever.

Comment: @TanmayLodha if my answer helped you you can use options on the left side of this answer to mark it as solving problem : - ).